# Video.js Playlist repeatedly plays video at index -1

Tags: javascript, node.js, video-streaming, video.js, playlist

I'm using video.js and [videojs-playlist](https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-playlist) to show a series of videos in a playlist. Each source is a url that streams from my MongoDB and Node server.

Outside of the playlist, the videos stream correctly. With the playlist library, only the first video plays over and over. Using the playlist [currentItem function](https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-playlist/blob/master/docs/api.md#playerplaylistcurrentitemnumber-index---number) I can see that the index is always -1, never changes, even if I try to do it programmatically. The only way it will change is if I manually click other videos in the list.

I believe the problem has to do with streaming and not reading from a file system, but I don't know enough about this subject to debug. Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<section class="main-preview-player">
  <video id="preview-player" class="video-js vjs-fluid vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto">
     <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
       <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
     </p>
  </video>
<div class="playlist-container  preview-player-dimensions vjs-fluid">
   <ol class="vjs-playlist"></ol>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(video);

function video() {
  var arr = arrayOfIds.split(','); // IDs for video URLs
  var player = videojs('preview-player');


 function getPlaylist() {
   var videos = arr.map(function(id) {
     return obj = {
       name: id,
       sources: [{ 
         src: "/api/mediaID/" + id, // URL for video stream
         type: "video/mp4"          // Is this right??
       }]
     }
   })

   player.playlist(videos, 0);
   player.playlistUi();
 }

  function playNext() {
    var num = player.playlist.currentItem();
    console.log(num); // Always logs '-1'

    player.playlist.next();
  }

  player.ready(function() {
    if(arrayOfIds.length) {
      getPlaylist();
    }

    player.on("ended", playNext);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source for videojs-playlist requires a full URL as a source. With HTML5 video tags, you can use `"/api/media/{ videoid }"` as the source for tag. I simply changed the src in my playlist array to `"http://localhost:3000/api/media/{ videoid }"`.

Answer (score 0):

Visiting the site videojs-play it looks like you're using the 'playNext' versus the autoadvance.

I don't see your play list, just this:

```
<ol class="vjs-playlist"></ol>
```

You may try using their example on page: https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-playlist

> // Play through the playlist automatically.
>   player.playlist.autoadvance(0);

There is more detail on this option on this page: https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-playlist/blob/master/docs/api.md#playerplaylistcurrentitemnumber-index---number

> **player.playlist.autoadvance([Number delay]) -> undefined**
>
> Sets up playlist auto-advance behavior.
>
> Once invoked, at the end of each video in the playlist, the plugin
>   will wait delay seconds before proceeding automatically to the next
>   video.
>
> Any value which is not a positive, finite integer, will be treated as
>   a request to cancel and reset the auto-advance behavior.
>
> If you change auto-advance during a delay, the auto-advance will be
>   canceled and it will not advance the next video, but it will use the
>   new timeout value for the following videos.
>
> // no wait before loading in the next item
>   player.playlist.autoadvance(0);
>
> // wait 5 seconds before loading in the next item
>   player.playlist.autoadvance(5);
>
> // reset and cancel the auto-advance player.playlist.autoadvance();

On this same page they also mention -1 always being displayed:

> Get the index of a string, source object, or playlist item in the
>   playlist. If not found, returns -1.

So, since you didn't post your playlist you may have an error there or it's just not called, or, more likely its because your video already played.

Comment: The autoadvance function has the same effect (playing the first video over an over). My playlist is being generated in the getPlaylist function in my JS code. The `<ol>` tag is displaying all of the videos in the playlist, it has little functionality and is working fine. It says that it only displays -1 if there is no video found. Which doesn't make sense to me because the first video is playing. I've read through the API docs already. Thanks.

Comment: I see your answer, but I can't comment below since I'm a newbie.

Comment: Have you tried using the 'autoadvance' just to see if that method works?

Comment: sorry. wish i could edit my comments. I see you tried that already. Perhaps there is an error in your playlist?

Comment: dang...hitting enter for line feed, dang. I ended up using [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) : HTML5 Audio & Video for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) which also allows for more than one player on a page. If a 2nd player is started the other players stop playing.